# How to click Android phone "home" button programmatically in espresso

Tags: java, android, testing, android-espresso

I need to simulate home button click in Espresso on Android phone.
I tried

onView(withId(android.R.id.home)).perform(click());

and onView(withContentDescription("Navigate up")).perform(click());

as some posts suggested but it always fails to find the view.
I'm new to Espresso and not sure how to debug it. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Better to use `withContentDescription(R.string.abc_action_bar_up_description)` rather than "Navigate up" but it doesn't act like a home button click anyway, it only uses the navigation bar's "back" button, so it would only work if you have it in your app.

If you want to simulate the *home* button click and you are using the [UI Automator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-automator) library, you can [simulate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiDevice.html#pressHome()) it like this

```
fun pressHome() {
    // Might be a good idea to initialize it somewhere else
    val uiDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation())
    uiDevice.pressHome()
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to or can't use UI Automator, you might try calling [`Intrstumentation.sendKeyDownUpSync()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.html#sendKeyDownUpSync(int))) with the `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME`.

Comment: Spasibo Mikhail, great comprehensive answer which works.

Comment: @alexbtr I'm glad I could help!